# jquery tablesorter + Jquery timepicker + Ajax call giving me duplicate entries in a <table>

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter, jquerydatetimepicker

Replicated here https://jsfiddle.net/a1fogpbm/
I'm producing data at work and trying to have the tables update every time you change the time. As soon as I added the datetimepicker, I get duplicates when I change the date, but when I click out, the ajax call refreshes a third time and gets rid of the duplicates.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
$(".data").remove();
$('.text').text('loading . . .');
$.ajax({

type:"GET",
url:"https://api.meetup.com/2/cities",
success: function(data) {

  //$('.text').text(JSON.stringify(result));

for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
  var this_city = data.results[i];

  $(".tbody").append(
    $("<tr/>",{"class": "data" } ).append(
      $("<td>").append(
        $("<div/>", {"class": "column-txt input duration", text: this_city.id})
      )
    ).append(
      $("<td>", {"class": "column-txt input status", text: this_city.city})

      ).append(
        $("<td>", {"class": "column-txt input status", text: this_city.state})

        ).append(
          $("<td>", {"class": "column-txt input status", text: "Dec-"+(this_city.ranking) +" 11:23:8"})

          )   

  );

}
$(".sortTable").trigger("update");},
dataType: 'jsonp',
  });

});

$(function() {
  $("#myTable").tablesorter();
  $('#from').datetimepicker();
  $("#from").on("change", function() {
  $('.btn').click();     });
});
```

Many thanks if anyone can figure it out

Comment: Maybe try clearing the tbody before appending the new content?

Comment: Something more than that "$(".data").remove();" ?

Comment: I mean add a `$(".tbody").remove()` _inside_ the ajax success callback function.

Comment: Thought I'd update you since your intuition solved my problem. While a $(".tbody").remove() inside the ajax callback still produced a duplicate in the original code, just moving the $(".data").remove(); into the ajax callback stopped the duplicates.
Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Add that solution as an answer and I'll upvote it :D

Answer (score 1):

Moving the $(".data").remove(); line into the ajax success callback function fixed the issue.